# Force index values to be present

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to construct a time series from a DataFrame. It's multi-indexed, and every move within one index corresponds to a constant shift in time. However, the indices are not all present. How could I expand the data (for future filling or other imputation) such that some levels of the indices are forced to have all their values?

```
# Example: here I0 is a running number and I1 to be forced to have 0 and 1 for every I0.

I0 | I1 || Value     ->    I0 | I1 || Value
---+----++-------          ---+----++-------
 0 |  0 ||   1              0 |  0 ||   1
   |  1 ||   2                |  1 ||   2
 1 |  0 ||   3              1 |  0 ||   3
 2 |  0 ||   5                |  1 ||   NaN
   |  1 ||   6              2 |  0 ||   5
 3 |  1 ||   8                |  1 ||   6
                            3 |  0 ||   NaN
                              |  1 ||   8
```

Here's a frame to try it on:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'I0': [0,0,1,2,2,3], 'I1': [0,1,0,0,1,1], 'Value': [1,2,3,5,6,8]})
df = df.set_index(['I0', 'I1'])
```

#### To clarify

I have the DataFrame in the form that the indices are already set. In the best case I'd like to be able to manipulate the MultiIndex such that the levels don't have to be converted back to columns. But I understand if that is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) with [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'I0': [0,0,1,2,2,3], 'I1': [0,1,0,0,1,1], 'Value': [1,2,3,5,6,8]})

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['I0'].unique(), [0,1]], names=['I0','I1'])
```

---

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([np.arange(df['I0'].max() + 1), 
                                  df['I1'].unique()], 
                                  names=['I0','I1'])
```

---

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['I0'].unique(), df['I1'].unique()], names=['I0','I1'])
df = df.set_index(['I0', 'I1']).reindex(mux)

print (df)
       Value
I0 I1       
0  0     1.0
   1     2.0
1  0     3.0
   1     NaN
2  0     5.0
   1     6.0
3  0     NaN
   1     8.0
```

EDIT:

After some discussion solution was changed - to preserve other levels of the MultiIndex, first is necessary to convert levels to integers (to avoid sorting as strings) and then use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html). To preserve `NaN`s use the parameter `dropna=False`:

```
a = df.index.get_level_values(0).astype(int)
b = df.index.get_level_values(1).astype(int)
c = df.index.get_level_values(2)   # String index level
d = df.index.get_level_values(3).astype(int)

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a, b, c, d], names=df.index.names)

df = df.unstack().stack(dropna=False)
```

Comment: To pick your brain a bit more, do the indices need to be converted to columns? You apparently operated on the data frame before `set_index` was called. Also, how does this carry over if there are multiple outer index levels that need to be preserved?

Comment: Hmm, weird, at least I cannot reference an index level with `df[idx]`... Throws a key error, yet you reference index levels in the code above. For the second question: I purposely tried to simplify the original question to maybe get a general solution, but I do have four index levels, only the innermost of which has to have this alternating 0,1,0,1 pattern. So I'd like to preserve the outer index levels, only expanding the one level. And one of the levels carries just auxiliary information about the row in question. So if I were to do a cartesian product, I'd get way more than is wanted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179461/discussion-between-jezrael-and-felix).